# What is solution for “none of....” in probability

Tags: probability

On any particular day, it’s 30% for snow find the probability of :

-None of the next 3 days

-Exactly one of the next 3 days

What is the solution of this qeustion 
I try the tree diagram like

30-30
  -70

70- 30
  - 70
  I think because it’s say none in three days so I decide to do like this 
0.3x0.7=0.21
0.21x3=0.63
 And for the second one just minus 1 
IT’S CORRECT?

Comment: Weclome to Math SE. Make sure you show some effort and that you tried for yourself. Just asking for an answer will likely get your post deleted/ignored.

Comment: Nope: it's not correct. Should be $(0.7)^3$ for none of the next three days.

Comment: Thank you sir so in second one I have to minus is it right

Comment: No. For the second one you have to consider three cases. snow-sun-sun, sun-snow-sun and sun-sun-snow. Each of them has probability $0.7 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.3 = 0.063$. Then multiply by 3 to get $0.189$.

Comment: Thank you again sir

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose the chance of snow is independant for each day, then the number of snowy days follows a binomial distribution

Let's $X$ be the number of snowy days in the next three days. Then $X\sim B(3,0.30)$ where $p=0.30$ is the chance there is snow on a given day. Then the chance to have exactly $i$ snowy days in the next three days is given by
$$P(X=i)={3\choose i}(0.30)^i(1-0.30)^{3-i}$$
The chance that none of the next three days Gets snow $(i=0)$ is
$$P(X=0)={3\choose 0}(0.30)^0(1-0.30)^{3-0}=(0.70)^3=0.343$$
The chance there is exactly one snowy days is
$$P(X=1)={3\choose 1}(0.30)^1(1-0.30)^{3-1}=3(0.30)(0.70)^2=0.441$$

Comment: Thank you very very much sir your answer help me understand more a lot

Comment: May I ask you more question can I apply this formula in the different question if it kinda same type

Comment: @user767286 It is hard to tell without seeing your other question. To use the binomial distribution, you need a fixed number of events. Each events needs to be independant and have the same chance of succes.